# R sub-setting netcdf file

Tags: r, r-raster, netcdf4

I am working with a lulc cover data from this source for the year 2018

https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/satellite-land-cover?tab=form

The data format is in netcdf and shows for each lat long the land cover classification. In order to read and create a raster from this netcdf, I did this:

```
library(ncdf4)
temp <- nc_open(file.name)
lon <- ncvar_get(temp, "lon")
lat <- ncvar_get(temp, "lat")
lccs <- ncvar_get(temp, "lccs_class", signedbyte = FALSE)
```

However, the netcdf file is so big that it takes ages to read the file. I only need a subset of the lat lon whose bounding box is defined as follows:

```
min lat: 8.125
max lat: 37.125
min lon: 68.125
max lon: 97.375
```

How can I subset the above netcdf using these bounding boxes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases you can do that like this

```
library(raster)
b <- brick("filename.nc")
e <- extent(8.125, 37.125, 68.125, 97.375)
x <- crop(b, e)
```